# Синонім до "зворотний зв'язок"

Tags: синоніми, одним-словом

Який синонім можна підібрати, або на що можна замінити **зворотний зв'язок**. Особливо цікаво почути відповідь в контексті комп'ютерних програм і веб-сайтів. Наприклад, форма **зворотного зв'язку**, адреса для **зворотного зв'язку**. Тобто те, що англійською передають "feedback", російською - "обратная связь"

Чи можна підібрати більш звучний і, по можливості, короткий вислів в українській мові?

Comment: англійське feedback у контексті електроних контурів дослівно буде - зворотне живлення; у контексті комунікацій з клієнтами - відгук

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Відгук**

Наприклад, *залиште відгук на цій сторінці або за телефоном*.

Вікісловник [пропонує](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) синоніми *назадній*, *поворотний*, що, очевидно, нам не підходять.

<sub>Вікіпедія [описує](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA) *зворотний звя'зок* лише в контексті теорії автоматичного управління. Також цікаво, що офіціний сайт української мови містить сторінку ["зворотній зв'язок"](https://ukrainskamova.com/index/0-3), хоча джерела [стверджують](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/), що правильно все таки "зворотний зв'язок".</sub>